# How to manage interrupt from accelerometer BMA220?

Tags: arduino-mega, interrupt, accelerometer

I would like to use the interrupt register from the BMA220 accelerometer in order to detect high-g shock. I am using a Mega2560 and the sensor is powered by 3.3 V. I use a voltage divider to convert the 5V from the card to 3.3V because the 5V pin gives more current. The memory map concerning the registers is shown below [image: Memory map for registers]
In the datasheet the section concerning high-g registers is as followed :
[image: High-g detection registers]
It is written that whenever a condition is met for the interrupt controller "an interrupt (logic '1') is issued through the INT pin of the sensor."

However after initializing the necessary registers (in I2C):

- 0xC for high_th
- 0xA for high_hy and high_dur
- 0x1C for en_high_x/y/z

I don't get my interrupt working. Using a voltmeter I always get a high value (3.3V) on the INT pin of my accelerometer eventhough it stays still and I wrote a threshold of 2G...

Here is the code I am using :

```
#include <BMA220.h>
#include "SEN0168.h"


BMA220 bma;
byte interruptPin = 2;
byte count = 0;
const uint8_t HIGH_SET = 0xA;
const uint8_t HIGH_LOW_TH = 0xC;
const uint8_t INTERRUPT_REG = 0x18; // to get the bit indicating an interrupt was detected, not used because of the INT pin
const uint8_t ENABLE = 0x1C;

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(74880);
   pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT);
   init_SEN0168(R4); // set sensitivity to 4G
   bma.setRegister(ENABLE, 0xF7); // enable high-g-detection, reset interrupt bit control and latch permanently
   bma.setRegister(HIGH_LOW_TH, 0x1); // Threshold of 1G
   bma.setRegister(HIGH_SET, 0x1); // No hysteresis and 2 signals needed to trigger
   attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin),counter, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
    if (count==1){
    Serial.print("x-axis: ");
    Serial.println(accel_range_SEN0168(X,R4));
    Serial.print("y-axis: ");
    Serial.println(accel_range_SEN0168(Y,R4));
    Serial.print("z-axis: ");
    Serial.println(accel_range_SEN0168(Z,R4));
    count =0;
    bma.setRegister(INTRP_RES_REG, 0xF7); // enable high-g-detection, reset interrupt bit control and latch permanently
    }
    else{
      Serial.println("No shock");
      count =0;
    }
}

void counter(){
  count +=1;
}
```

Am I missing something to clear in one register ? Or maybe since the card is in 5V and the sensor 3.3V logic there is a problem to detect change on the interrupt pin ?  Also I don't know if I understand properly the "logic 1". For me it means it puts the pin to "HIGH".

I use a part of the library written by Sönke Carstens-Behrens to set the registers from here : https://github.com/scbrac/BMA220.

I really need this interrupt pin to work...

Thank you for your help !

Comment: `I use a voltage divider to convert the 5V from the card to 3.3V because the 5V pin gives more current.` errr.... **NO!**  https://majenko.co.uk/blog/why-you-cant-use-resistors-voltage-regulator

Comment: Ok thank you for the article it answers simply the problem of voltage divider ! So it means I just cannot make my device work properly without a voltage regulator ? However I used to record some data that way and it was working. Appart from this, is there something in my code that shouldn't work ?

Comment: I am not too familiar with that unit, so I can't be sure.  However, you don't need a voltage regulator. Just use the 3.3V pin to power it. On modern Arduinos the 3.3V pin can provide plenty of power. The old rumour that 3.3V is limited to 50mA is wrong, and has been for many years.

Comment: Ok I will use the 3.3V then, thank you ! Has anybody an idea about the logic 1 interrupt ?

Comment: You should, at least for testing, set `lat_int` to 0b111 so it latches the interrupt on the pin until you manually reset it by setting `reset_int` to 1.  At the moment you have such a brief interrupt that you'll be hard pressed to see it even if it does trigger.

Comment: Ok so I tried to change the latch duration for many values in the register 0x1C as you can see in the updated code (for permanent latching) but still no detection of the shock... and the threshold is set to only 1G with no hysteresys

Comment: By changing HIGH to LOW of the interrupt I get record from the accelerometer but it doesn't respect the high-g condition...

Comment: The interrupt should be RISING, FALLING or LOW. There is no HIGH.

Comment: Ok but it is written that when a condition is met a logic 1 will be sent via the INT pin. How am I suppose to detect it ? Also I made a mask to get the bit corresponding to high_int (set to 1 if an interrupt has been triggered) in register 0x18 and this bit is always 1 ! I don't understand...

Comment: You would use RISING, which is a change from LOW to HIGH to catch the interrupt. As to why it's always HIGH I have no idea.  However most INT pins I have come across are active LOW not active HIGH...

Comment: I tried both RISING and LOW but I don't get the expected behaviour by the accelerometer... So nobody has experience with this accelerometer to share ?

Comment: Maybe on ee.se they may. It's more general electronics than Arduino really.

Comment: ee.se ? It tells me the website doesn't exist

Comment: It's shorthand for electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oh ! OK I didn't know sorry ^^'... Well thank you for help Majenko !

Comment: That's ok... my fault for assuming everyone had the same strange mind as I do :P  I was using my phone, so easier to type shorthand on there.

Comment: EE.se has people that are more likely to understand the internal configuration of the chip and have experience with it.  You should take the Arduino out of the mix for the interrupt reading and instead connect it to an oscilloscope or logic analyser that can independently confirm the presence or not of an interrupt event.  Once you are happy that the interrupt is being configured correctly and is occurring on the pin as you require it to then you can start tackling the Arduino code to read the interrupt.

Comment: Thanks it is what I am doing right now and I hope I will get the result I want !

Comment: Majenko maybe you know what does this mean : 1 LSB is 2*(LSB of acc_data) ? Because now I get a better behaviour of my accelerometer but I wrote 0x8 for the threshold which is surely not 8G according to the shake I give to it

Comment: The least significant bit of the value is double the least significant bit of the accelerometer data.  So 1 is 0.5g, 2 is 1g, 3 is 1.5g, etc. Or that's my interpretation

Comment: Ok it is what I was thinking too ! Thanks ! What is funny is that when I put 0x8 I have a better behaviour of the interrupt but I should get 4G threshold which is surely not what I am giving the accelerometer. When I put 0x4 it activates the INT pin too often eventhough I just move slightly the sensor...Maybe I should play with hysteresis now